How can I remove the lowest possible amount of rows in a dataset of two columns such that each column has unique values?
I am using a pandas dataframe, I thought about using max flow in networkx, but I think that's a bit overkill, is there an alternative?
I tried to use
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4],
                   'column2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7]})

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)

# Function to remove the lowest possible number of rows
def remove_duplicate_rows(df):
    # Get the unique values in each column
    df.drop_duplicates(subset='column1', inplace=True)

    df.drop_duplicates(subset='column2', inplace=True)

    # Apply the mask to the DataFrame and return the result
    return df

# Apply the function to the DataFrame
result = remove_duplicate_rows(df)

print("\nResulting DataFrame:")
print(result)

Output:
Original DataFrame:
   column1  column2
0        1        5
1        2        6
2        3        7
3        1        8
4        3        9
5        4        7

Resulting DataFrame:
   column1  column2
0        1        5
1        2        6
2        3        7

That removes too many rows, a valid output could be:
Resulting DataFrame:
   column1  column2
0        1        5
1        2        6
2        3        9
3        4        7


read notice : [mre]

@Panda Kim I edited it, is it okay now?

you could do a first pass counting number of duplicates for each column and then second pass dropping duplicates by removing first the bigger counts.

@JoachimHuet that won't work, you can easily craft counter-examples in which the edges with higher duplicate counts would be the ones to select. IMO this problem cannot be solved efficiently with pure pandas.

This is literally the maximum independent set problem, so whether or not your algorithm is "overkill" depends on whether (1) You absolutely want an optimal solution or can be satisfied with a simpler algorithm that sometimes remove a few more rows than necessary (2) is your actual instance complicated and are there many rows that have duplicates in the two columns, or are the duplicates mostly isolated?

Your problem is literally the maximum independent set problem in the graph with one vertex per row and an edge between two vertices if these rows have an element in common in one of the two columns.
There is a function in networkx to solve the maximum independent set problem.
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.approximation.clique import maximum_independent_set
from itertools import combinations

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4],
                   'column2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7]})

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(range(len(df)))
rows = ((i,(a,b)) for (i,(a,b)) in df.iterrows())
G.add_edges_from((i,j) for (i,(a,b)),(j,(c,d)) in combinations(rows,2) if a==c or b==d)

mis = maximum_independent_set(G)

new_df = df.iloc[sorted(mis)]

print(new_df)
#    column1  column2
# 0        1        5
# 1        2        6
# 4        3        9
# 5        4        7


is there anything faster than O(n^2)?

I tried the following, for your example it works, maybe you can try other examples to see if it still works.
Here is what I do:

count the number of occurences in one of the 2 columns and add it as a third column
sort your dataframe by that column
drop duplicates on the other column by keeping 'first' (would mean less occurences in other column)
drop duplicates in the remaining column just to make sure, order does not matter anymore

import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4],
                   'column2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7]})

df['column2_count'] = df['column2'].map(df['column2'].value_counts())
df.sort_values('column2_count', inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['column1'], keep='first', inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['column2'], keep='first', inplace=True)
df[['column1', 'column2']].reset_index(drop=True)

And of course it should work no matter which column you pick first.
Edit:
Like @mozway said, this is not working with the following example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1], 
                   'column2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 9, 9]})


You probably want to drop rows that have duplicates in both columns first.

Could do but is it really necessary ? They will get deleted anyway (:

As commented to the question, this is not a working strategy. Counterexample for which it will fail: df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1], 'column2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 9, 9]})

(1,10) (1,11) (2,10) which ones will you drop?

@mozway aight, you are right, not a trivial one indeed. We could randomly sort the dataframe n times and drop duplicates col1 then col2 every time and get the best result in the end ^^

That seems like a non-robust and expensive strategy ;)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4],
                   'y': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7]})

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)

def remove_duplicate_rows(df):
    df.drop_duplicates(subset='x', inplace=True, keep='last')
    df.drop_duplicates(subset='y', inplace=True, keep='last')
    df.sort_values("x", inplace=True)
    df.rename(columns={'x': 'column1', 'y': 'column2'}, inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return df
result = remove_duplicate_rows(df)
print("\nResulting DataFrame:")
print(result)


Needs explanation.

This will only work for the given example but if you just revert the example it does not work anymore. df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1], 'column2': [7, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]})
